# matplotlib 3D scatter plot with legend

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, mplot3d

I have a table with 3 columns and 16 rows. I want to create a 3D plot to visualize each row as a marker on the plot. To do this I used the first column as X, the second column as Y, and the third one as Z.
The data looks something like it :

```
>>> print(data.head())

                            Penicilin  Streptomycin   Neomycin Gram Staining 
Bacteria                                                                     
Aerobacter aerogenes            870.0            1.0      1.60       negative
Brucella abortus                  1.0            2.0      0.02       negative
Escherichia coli                100.0            0.4      0.10       negative
Klebsiella pneumoniae           850.0            1.2      1.00       negative
Mycobacterium tuberculosis      800.0            5.0      2.00       negative
```

I used this code to plot the data:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')

ax.scatter(X, Y, Z, label=data.index.values, marker='o' )


ax.set_xlabel('Penicilin')
ax.set_ylabel('Streptomycin')
ax.set_zlabel('Neomycin')
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]
The 3D plot is correct but the problem is with the legend.

**question**:

I want each point in the plot to be distinguishable from the others so that the user can understand that each point is which bacteria.

how to set a different marker for each row of dataframe or even a different color for it? The legend is not clear as well.

Answer (score 3):

By drawing a graph with markers and data as one line, you can draw a scatter plot with different markers for each.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')

markers = ['o','^','x','>','<']
for idx, row in data.iterrows():
#     print(idx,row)
    ax.scatter(row['Penicilin'], row['Streptomycin'], row['Neomycin Gram'], label=row['Bacteria'], marker=markers[idx])

ax.set_xlabel('Penicilin')
ax.set_ylabel('Streptomycin')
ax.set_zlabel('Neomycin')
ax.legend(loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.15, 1.0))
plt.show()
```

[image]